# How to superimpose 3 images with red, green, and blue separate components using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, colors

Given three versions of an image, each with one of the red, green, and blue components, is there any way to superimpose them to produce the original image using HTML and CSS?

I can use this HTML to superimpose them:

```
<div id="container">
    <img class="color" id="red"   src="red"></div>
    <img class="color" id="green" src="green"></div>
    <img class="color" id="blue"  src="blue"></div>
</div>
```

And this CSS to blend them:

```
#container { position: relative; width: 20em; height: 20em; }
.color     { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#red   { opacity: 1; }
#green { opacity: .5; }
#blue  { opacity: .333; }
```

It all works fine, except that the displayed color intensity is only 1/3 of what it should be and the result looks very dark.

Is there any way to "boost" the color values by a factor of 3?

(Note that this is *not* a duplicate of "[Generate an image through its red, green and blue components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943706/generate-an-image-through-its-red-green-and-blue-components)", which is about python.)

EDIT (simplified example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
        .color { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
        #container { position: relative;  width: 20em; height: 20em; }
        #red   { background: rgba(256,0,0,1); }
        #green { background: rgba(0,256,0,.5); }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="color" id="red"></div>
        <div class="color" id="green"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This simply combines two colors, red and green.
The result is olive, rgb(128,128,0), but I want yellow rgb(255,255,0).

Comment: Maybe try something like `filter: brightness(1.75);` on the pictures you want brighter. (You might have to change the values depending on the darkness imposed by the opacity/overlay of the other images)

Comment: Sorry, I only used 1.75 as an example, I just re-read your question and saw you were looking for a brightness increase of a factor of 3. If that's the case, use 300% (Based on your example, I would go 300% for the blue and 200% for the green)

Comment: could you provide code with images? might be helpful.

Comment: Do you have transparency in your original image? What's the background like? Solid color?

Comment: Sure. I'll do it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To brighten an image, use the `filter: brightness();` property in your CSS. For your example, I would set your blue image to `filter: brightness(300%);`, and your green image to `filter: brightness(200%);` or `filter: brightness(2);`.

Comment: That did it.  Setting brightness(300%) on the div that contained the three images did the trick.  (And 200% on the second example correctly turned olive into yellow.)  I hadn't considered the brightness filter because I had incorrectly assumed that it behaves the same as the "brightness" control on a monitor (adding white to the dark areas), and didn't realize that it behaves like the "color" control.